# CSS gradients start to fade when generating more lines every x%

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a gradient that simply shows a red line every x%.

When I start generating more lines the red stripes seems to start fading into white.
the `.four-stripes` selector gives a nice result, but when I add one more red line, like in `more-stripes` everything starts to get blurry...
See [codepen for an example](https://codepen.io/willemvanpelt/pen/YzPEWRq):

```css
div {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 20px;
}

.four-stripes {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,red 0.00% 0.27%,transparent 0.27% 1.92%,red 1.92% 2.19%,transparent 2.19% 3.84%,red 3.84% 4.11%,transparent 4.11% 5.75%,red 5.75% 6.03%,transparent 6.03% 100%);
}

.more-stripes {
 background: linear-gradient(90deg,red 0.00% 0.27%,transparent 0.27% 1.92%,red 1.92% 2.19%,transparent 2.19% 3.84%,red 3.84% 4.11%,transparent 4.11% 5.75%,red 5.75% 6.03%,transparent 6.03% 7.67%,red 7.67% 7.95%,transparent 7.95% 100%)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="four-stripes"></div>
  <div class="more-stripes"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Answer (score 1):

Using "repeating-linear-gradient" may help.

```css
div {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 20px;
}

.more-stripes {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    red,
    red 5px,
    transparent 5px,
    transparent 20px
  );
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="more-stripes"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make the gradient easy and adjust the `background-size`.

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  margin:5px;
}

.four-stripes {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right,red 5px,transparent 0 100%)
    left/25% 100%;
}

.more-stripes {
 background: 
    linear-gradient(to right,red 5px,transparent 0 100%)
    left/15% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="four-stripes"></div>
  <div class="more-stripes"></div>
</div>
```

Or like this if you want to keep a fixed distance between stripes:

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  margin:5px;
}

.four-stripes {
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,red 0 5px,transparent 0 40px)
    left/calc(4*40px) 100% no-repeat;
}

.more-stripes {
 background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right,red 0 5px,transparent 0 40px)
    left/calc(6*40px) 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="four-stripes"></div>
  <div class="more-stripes"></div>
</div>
```